# How to test auth middleware protected API endpoints in laravel8 with PHPUnit?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-8, tdd

I have an API endpoint(/post) which is protected with passport authentication. Client access this endpoint with a bearer token they get with another(/register) API endpoint.

My user model is custom model named AppUser and has HasFactory trait included but when I create a actingAs user for testing `$this->actingAs(AppUser::factory()->create());` this throws an error that says
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unknown format "name" in /var/www/api_devbytes/vendor/fakerphp/faker/src/Faker/Generator.php`.

How do I test this(/post) endpoint?

I tried to do create user with default User model like this -
`$this->actingAs(User::factory()->create());`
but this is throws following error
`Expected type 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable'. Found 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model'`

Comment: I see a thread going on in laracast forum with similar issue mentioned by you. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/default-user-factory-gives-invalidargumentexception-unknown-formatter-name 
This could be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Here it is -

Passport provides a way to do this

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
Passport::actingAs(CustomUserModel::factory()->create());
```

add a factory class with name `CustomFactory` in `Database\Factories`